# Convert String to ArratList

Tags: java, android

How to convert string to array list with simple process ?

it's my string value

```
String data = "[{"ID":"101","NAME":"ARNOLD","PHONE":"344164563"},{"ID":"102","NAME":"JESSICA","PHONE":"674546463"}]";
```

I want to convert that to list_data

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data = new ArrayList<>();
```

Thanks..

Comment: This is actually a JSON array - why not use some JSON parser to parse this?

Comment: What was your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GSON to parse it, it is available at https://github.com/google/gson it should do this for you just with a call like

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Map<String,String>> result = new Gson().fromJson(data, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your string is wrong, should be :

```
data = "[{\"ID\":\"101\",\"NAME\":\"ARNOLD\",\"PHONE\":\"344164563\"},{\"ID\":\"102\",\"NAME\":\"JESSICA\",\"PHONE\":\"674546463\"}]";
```

Second, you string has a json format, so, the best option is Gson.

```
Class Person {
public string ID;
public string NAME;
public string PHONE;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();

Person [] pArray= gson.fromJson(jsonString, Person [].class);
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

A json parser is probably what you are looking for, but if your data is the same as your example something like this might work..

```
final String[] people = data.split("},{");
final List<Map<String, String>> list_data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    final String person = people[i].replaceAll("[", "")
                                   .replaceAll("{", "")
                                   .replaceAll("}", "")
                                   .replaceAll("]", "");
    final String[] attributes = person.split(",");
    final Map<String, String> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (final String attribute : attributes) {
        attributeMap.put(attribute.split(":")[0], attribute.split(":")[1])
    }
    list_data.add(attributeMap);
}
```